# Subplots in bookdown repeating the caption

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

[The section of the bookdown manual on generating figures](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html) demonstrates a case where `include_graphics()` can be given a vector of paths of length > 1, producing a number of subplots with a single caption:

[image]

However, when I try this in my fork of [thesisdown](https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown), in the PDF output I get the figure caption (and, judging by the spacing, the entire figure environment) repeated for each subplot. Here is a reproducible example:

````
---
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
toc: false
---


```{r, echo = FALSE}
for(i in 1:3){
  jpeg(filename = paste0("temp_", i, ".jpg"), width = 600, height = 250)
  plot(cars)
  title(main = i)
  dev.off()
}
```

```{r fig.cap = "Caption", out.width="100%", fig.ncol = 1, echo = FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics(paste0("temp_", 1:3, ".jpg"))
```
````

[image]

I was hoping more for the five images stacked, with a single caption at the bottom. This also appears to be breaking the figure cross-referencing, as each plot has its own figure number and cross-references to the chunk render as `??`.

Comment: Added a reproducible example: it is harder with rmarkdown/bookdown but usually possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting subfigures requires a few additional settings to be set in the chunk header.

- `fig.subcap` is a list of the captions for subfigures
- `fig.ncol`: the number of columns of subfigures
- `out.width`: the output width of the figures. You will normally set this 100% divided by the number of sub columns.

Subfigures are built using the `subfig` package. You can either include this within your LaTeX bookdown template, or alternative you can added it to the YAML as follows:

Here is an example:

````
---
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
toc: false
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{subfig}
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
for(i in 1:3){
  jpeg(filename = paste0("temp_", i, ".jpg"), width = 600, height = 250)
  plot(cars)
  title(main = i)
  dev.off()
}
```

```{r fig.cap = "Caption", out.width="100%", fig.ncol = 1, echo = FALSE, fig.subcap= c("First", "Second", "Third")}
knitr::include_graphics(paste0("temp_", 1:3, ".jpg"))
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! Do you happen to know whether the `position` argument from `subfig1 is supported to move the subcaptions above their respective figures? I tried supplying `fig.position = 'top'` to the chunk, but no dice.

Comment: You will have to probably alter the settings of the `subfig` package and add some LaTeX to the document. Check out the package here: http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf . If you cannot work it out might be worth making another question

Comment: Passing the argument in the `usepackage` command did the trick: `\usepackage[position=top]{subfig}`